# companion object and function with default value

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class with default values `isEnabled: Boolean = true` in function `getCustomClass`

```
class CustomClass(_className: String, _isEnabled: Boolean) {

    private val className: String = _className
    private val isEnabled: Boolean = _isEnabled

    companion object {
        fun getCustomClass(className: String, isEnabled: Boolean = true): CustomClass {
            return CustomClass(className, isEnabled)
        }
    }
}
```

Why can't I use this constructor:

```
CustomClass.Companion.getCustomClass(MyClass.class.getSimpleName());
```

Comment: um, you tell me. What error does the compiler give?

Comment: Are you calling this from Java? Java does not support default arguments. You can add `@JvmOverloads` so it generates additional methods

Comment: @RobCo Thanks. I forgot this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are calling this from Java. Java does not support default arguments.

You could add `@JvmOverloads` to the functions so it generates all the additional overload methods that can be called from Java.